Как сжимать файлы лога nginx и не перезатирать старые?
Нашел настройку:
access_log /path_to_logs/access.log buffer=10m;

На сколько я правильно понял, nginx будет его перезаписывать, если он переполнится.
Что надо указать, чтобы он его не перезаписывал, а сжимал и сохранял в той же папки сжатый архив лога?
Я правильно понимаю, что можно зайти в /etc/logrotate.d/nginx и там скопировать и вставить дефолтный ротатор и в вставленнном указать свой путь и будет работать?

Nginx ничего не будет перезаписывать. buffer это не размер файла, а размер памяти в который nginx будет хранить логи перед записью их в файл. Это нужно что бы не писать на диск слишком часто потому то запись на диск довольно медленная операция. Так что настраивайте стандартный logrotate

@Alexey Ten я же могу просто скопировать и вставить ниже, но со своим путем только к файлу как написал в вопросе? И тогда правила дефолтного логирования применятся к моим логам?

Да, можете скопировать. Или даже просто в том же конфиге добавить путь к своему файлу.
